# Initializing a OpenGL VBO with a struct

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, opengl-4

Im having problems to add a `struct` to a OpenGL VBO

This is my `struct`

```cpp
struct Vertex {

    //vertices
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;

    //texture coordinates
    std::vector<glm::vec3> texCord;
}
```

This is how im assigning and initializing the VBO

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &buffer.VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer.VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer.EBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.VAO);

//Initialize buffer data 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            vertex.vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3) +
            vertex.texCord.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3)
            &vertex,
            GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//indices attribute
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex.indices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &vertex.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//vertices coordinates attribute
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, vertices));

//texture coordinates attribute
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texCord));
```

And my draw command looks like this

```cpp
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(buffer.VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertex.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Is it possible to initialize buffer data with a raw `struct` and if yes how?

Comment: The design by itself is not  good. Why name the struct `Vertex` and store multiple vetices inside?

Comment: @MartinPerry The struct name isn´t the best, thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) stores a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. However, you must pass a consecutive buffer to  [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml).
Create the object's data store with `glBufferData`, but use [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) to initialize the buffer:

```cpp
size_t vertexSize = vertex.vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3);
size_t texCordSize = vertex.texCord.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize + texCordSize, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexSize, vertex.vertices.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize, texCordSize, vertex.texCord.data());
```

Comment: When my draw command gets excuted, it is throwing the following exception `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9B83BE740 (nvoglv64.dll) in HotEvo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.`. My draw command looks like that `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertex.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);  glBindVertexArray(0);` Any Ideas what might be wrong now?

Comment: Is this a new question? For the use of `glDrawElements` you must specify an index buffer. If you don't have an index buffer, you have to use  `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: I am specify it already, I just sniped it out for readabilty purpoeses but i added it now and also my drawing command into my question. Can you spot a Problem? Thanks for the help already with `glBufferSubData`!

Comment: @Denmuell Why is the size of the element buffer `vertex.indices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2)`? The indices have to be integral.

Comment: Is the VAO already bound, when you bind the element buffer? See [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers)

Comment: You spotted an error regarding the size of the element buffer. It now looks like this: `vertex.indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int) `. But im still getting the same error message

Comment: Regarding the binding, i made a typo at `glBindVertexArray(scene[i].buffer.VBO);` I did correct it in the question now and changed VBO to VAO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231074/discussion-between-denmuell-and-rabbid76).

Comment: @Denmuell Do you call somewhere `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`. If so, remove it.

Comment: Nope im not calling it somewhere. Im just calling the EBO when I´m initializing the indices

Comment: Where do you call `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.VBO);`?

Comment: I can just guess here. I can't debug your application with only seeing the code snippet in the question. I recommend reading [Khronos OpenGL wiki - Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output). See also [GitHub - graphics-snippets - C++ code snippets - Debug context and Debug output](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/documentation/cpp_code_snippets.md#debug-context-and-debug-output)

Comment: Thanks for recommending that and also for helping me so far. I probably need to invest more time into the documenation of OpenGL.

Comment: If you are still intrested in finding the error tho then here is my like to the github repo https://github.com/0xdenmuell/HotEvo/tree/in_progress

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rabbid76 I now solved my problem. Code is down below.

Note: I need to create the buffer before filling data with `glBufferSubData`

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &buffer.VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer.VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer.EBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.VAO);

int vertexSize = sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertex.vertices.size();
int texCordSize = sizeof(glm::vec2) * vertex.texCord.size();
int totalSize = vertexSize + texCordSize;

int indicesSize = sizeof(unsigned int) * vertex.indices.size();

//Create Buffer dynamically
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//Fill the buffer with data 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.VBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexSize, vertex.vertices.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize, texCordSize, vertex.texCord.data());

//indices attribute
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesSize, vertex.indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//position attribute
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec3) + sizeof(glm::vec2), (void*)0);
        
//texture attribute
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec3) + sizeof(glm::vec2), (void*)sizeof(glm::vec3));

glBindVertexArray(0);
```